# Cause outer iframe to navigate from deeply nested child iframe

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, iframe

I need help to reload an `iframe` nested within two more iframes, already tried `parent.document` and `Response.Redirect` but nothing does what I ask.

If I use `Response.Redirect (URL)`, `iframe 1` is reloaded inside of `iframe 3`.

If I try to use:

```
parent.document.getelementbyid ('iframe1')
```

OR

```
parent.document.getelementbyid ('iframe3')
```

OR

```
parent.document.getelementbyid ('<%=iframe1.ClientID.ClientID %>')
```

OR

```
parent.document.getelementbyid ('<%=iframe3.ClientID.ClientID %>')
```

`null` is returned.

I've attached an image to see what I want to do:

[image]

I want that by clicking the button inside `iframe 3`, that `iframe 1` is reloaded.

Comment: Essentially a good question, but had nothing to do with jquery. You are aware that causing a server-side `Redirect` on the inner iframe cannot possibly affect the outer iframe because on the server they have no relationship to each other, right?

Comment: Yes, but if i do a redirect in inner frame, the frame 1 will reload in inner frame, and then i will have more 3 frames.

Answer (score 0):

I've made it, just by parent.location='url'.